# Compare two columns for new values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to come up with a formula that will allow me to compare two columns of names (A & B) and tell me how many **new** names there are in column B, that are not present in column A.  That is, names that are not present in column A, but are present in column B, and return this as a numerical value.

Any ideas??

Comment: What do you mean by `new` name?

Comment: @harun24hr I mean to say a name that is not present in column A, but is present in column B.

Comment: Assuming your data is in A1:A10, and B1:B10, you could try (in column C), `=Countif($A$1:$A$10,$B1)` This will see if the text in B1 is in column A, and if so, how many times it is there.  To do the opposite, just change the range to column B, and put `$A1` as the lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Quick an simple way is to drag a box/highlight around all the data you want to check (eg columns A and B) and then press F5 to open the goto box. Click special at the bottom and then check the 'Row differences' radio button. Click OK and it will highlight all differences.

Comment: Or if you wanted a count rather then to see the actual data thats different then use COUNTIF like in @BruceWayne's comment above

Answer (score 0):

If you use a helper column then it would easier to achieve that.
Suppose your data in `Column A` and `Column B` then use `Column C` as helper column put this formula in `C2` cell.

```
=IF(B2="","",IFERROR(MATCH(B2,A:A,0),"New"))
```

Then put below formula in `D2` cell.

```
=COUNTIF(C:C,"New")
```

[image]

Comment: You can use any column as helper column and then hide it.